# Use tty to pass serial data - communication between host & guest

Tags: serial-port, communication, qemu, tty

I'm using QEMU and here is my problem : I want to send basic data from host to guest.

I first tried using virtio-serial, but I can't modify my guest kernel (2.6.32) => virtio-console wasn't made to support the virtio-serial communication.
I can't use USB nor TCP:IP... Yes it's painful.

I thought about using the TTY on my guest, then connected to my host using chardevs :

```
qemu-system-i386 image.raw -chardev socket,path=mysock,server,nowait,id=sok -serial pty -serial chardev:sok -nographic
```

That works almost as intended... Problem, the data isn't sent to the guest through my socket until I enter a '\r' (new line), which corresponds to a 0xA in hexa. And some of my data can take this value !

Is there a way to configure a tty so it doesn't recognize some characters as options ? Or better : a simple way to send data host <=> guest

Comment: *"Is there a way to configure a tty so it doesn't recognize some characters as options"* -- Yes, it's called "raw" (or non-canonical) mode.  Use shell command `stty -F /dev/xxx raw` (or `-raw` to revert back to canonical mode).

Comment: Thanks, now that almost works !
Now, I just have some unwanted data on the guest and the host, probably due to the speed.
Is it possible to modify the "speed" of a socket ?

Comment: Turns out, I only have weird data on coming from my tty on my host : series of "0x5e 0x40 0x48 0x1"... I never send 0x5e for instance...